# How to use Google apps with VPN on? (Android 10)

Tags: google

I am using VPN because Google apps only work via proxied connections but recently all of the Google apps stop working if I have the VPN mode on (if I switch to NAT mode they works). I think Google detects VPN and disable its apps' network requests.

P.S. the servers work. The same phone running Android 9 works. Also other devices running Android 5 / 6 /7 works too.

Comment: What type of VPN are you talking about? A corporate VPN or one of the free/paid VPN providers?

Comment: VPN mode, not a specific VPN, any VPN will rely on VPN mode (or NAT mode). Read about what it is here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService

Comment: Here is an additional documentation on this API: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/vpn

Comment: The reason I was asking is not the on-device part but but the network the VPN endpoint is located in. If there is a SSL/TLS interception proxy active (aka Man-in-the-Middle attack) Google Playstore does not work because it performs certificate pinning.

Comment: The server isn't an issue, I own the servers - if I use the NAT mode it works. Also older devices work too (Android 5 / 6).

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean with NAT mode. Usually the VPN just connects the client to a different network and it is not providing any routing services. You should edit your question and give more details on your set-up. Which VPN server you use what VPN settings you have on the device and so on.

Comment: NAT (network address translation) mode is a mode that doesn't rely on the VPN interface provided by android but rather directly taking over the TUN. I am not adding any of the server side information because it is clearly a client side issue - because all other devices running older versions of Android connecting via the same VPN works. If you care to know the servers are a bunch of computers in the US and they provide routing services.

Comment: "I think Google detects VPN" isn't that already an answer? google coorporates with government

Comment: @alecxs how do we cripple the detection?

Comment: idk. do we need google apps?

Comment: It's funny google apps just work again today even with the vpn on, I then restart the phone and they still work with the vpn on, I restarted a few more times and they kept working...